# A PHP HTML parser that lets me do class select and get parent nodes

Tags: php, html, screen-scraping

So I'm in a situation where I am scraping a website with PHP and I need to be able to get a node based on it's css class. I need to get a ul tag that doesn't have an id attribute but does have a css class.  I, then need to get only li tags inside it which contain specific anchor tags, not all the li tags.

I've looked through DOMDocument, Zend_Dom, and neither have both of the requirements, class selections and dom traversal(specifically ascending to parents).

Comment: DOMDocument can do this, you should include some sample of the HTML

Answer (score 2):

You could use [querypath](/questions/tagged/querypath) and then something like this might work:

```
htmlqp($html)->find("ul.class")->not("#id")
             ->find('li a[href*="specific"]')->parent()
// then foreach over it or use ->writeHTML() for extraction
```

See http://api.querypath.org/docs/class_query_path.html for the API.

(Traversing is much easier, if you don't use the fiddly DOMDocument.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).  Selecting by class in XPath is a pain, but it can be done.

Here is some sample (and totally valid!) HTML:

```
$html = <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<title>Document Title</title>
<ul id="myid"><li>myid-listitem1</ul>
<ul class="foo 
theclass
"><li>list2-item1<li>list2-item2</ul>
<ul id="myid2" class="foo&#xD;theclass bar"><li>list3-item1<li>list3-item2</ul>
EOT
;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xp->query("/html/body//ul[not(@id) and contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '), ' theclass ')]");

var_dump($nodes->length);
```

If you are using PHP 5.3, you can simplify this a bit by registering an XPath function in php. (Note that you can register functions for use in XPath expressions by `XSLTProcessor` starting at PHP 5.1, but not directly for `DOMXPath`.)

```
function hasToken($nodearray, $token) {
    foreach ($nodearray as $node) {
        if ($node->nodeValue===null or !hasTokenS($node->nodeValue, $token)) {
            return False;
        }
    }
    return True;
    // I could even return nodes or document fragments if I wanted!
}
function hasTokenS($str, $token) {
    $str = trim($str, "\r\n\t ");
    $tokens = preg_split('/[\r\n\t ]+/', $str);
    return in_array($token, $tokens);
}

$xp->registerNamespace('php', 'http://php.net/xpath');
$xp->registerPhpFunctions(array('hasToken', 'hasTokenS'));

// These two are equivalent:
$nodes1 = $xp->query("/html/body//ul[not(@id) and php:function('hasToken', @class, 'theclass')]");
$nodes2 = $xp->query("/html/body//ul[not(@id) and php:functionString('hasTokenS', @class, 'theclass')]");

var_dump($nodes1->length);
var_dump($nodes1->item(0));
var_dump($nodes2->length);
var_dump($nodes2->item(0));
```

If `DOMDocument` is just not parsing your HTML very well, you can use the [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) parser, which will return a DOMDocument:

```
require_once('lib/HTML5/Parser.php'); // or where-ever you put it
$dom = HTML5_Parser::parse($html);
// $dom is a plain DOMDocument object, created according to html5 parsing rules
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/