# Replace only last number (price) in a string using regex and PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string which contains several different prices. This is the string:

```
<div class="price-box">
<p class="old-price">
    <span class="price" id="old-price-145">
        ab 64,00 € *
    </span>
</p>
<p class="special-price">
    <span class="price" id="product-price-145">
        ab 27,00 € *
    </span>
</p>
```

I want to replace only the 27,00 with something else, not the € an not the ab, just the price. I tried several regexes but failed so far. The prices **differ**, but the structure stays the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Use built-in DOM parser of PHP instead.

Comment: Can you give me some more details please?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php. Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584554/a-php-html-parser-that-lets-me-do-class-select-and-get-parent-nodes

Comment: I am not allowed to add any extra libs, so I guess this wont work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with stema about HTML parser, but if you really want to use regex, how about:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(class="special-price">.*?)\d+,\d+/s', "$1 55,00", $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really can't use a DOM/HTML parser and you are sure about the structure, you can try this

```
(class="special-price">.*[\r\n]{1,2}.*[\r\n]{1,2}[^\d]*)[\d,]+
```

and replace with `$1` and your new price

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?308dk)

```
(                                     # Start the capturing group
class="special-price">.*[\r\n]{1,2}   # match from the "class="special-price""
.*[\r\n]{1,2}                         # match the following row
[^\d]*)                               # match anything that is not a digit and close the capt. group
[\d,]+                                # Match the price
```

The part in the capturing group is stored in `$1`, therefor tokeep this part you need to put it first into your replace string.

Comment: Thanks, Ill try it in some minutes!

Answer (score 1):

Now to change a text between two variables you can do the following:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
$string = " ".$string;
$ini = strpos($string,$start);
if ($ini == 0) return "";
$ini += strlen($start);
$len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}


$fullstring = "ab 64,00 € *";
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, "ab ", "€ *");

echo $parsed; // (result = 64,00)
$newValue = $parsed + 10; //Do Whatever you want here
echo "ab " . $newValue . " € *"; // ab 74 € *
```

If you want to change the money format. **money_format()**

Please check this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

You can change the numbers format and the way you would like them to be viewed in the page.

Comment: Thanks, but still I have to do it to both prices, the 27 and the 64. I only want the last price from that string. I dont want to touch the 64,00.

Comment: Can you paste the code in the loop so we can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
preg_replace('/ab [0-9,] € */', 'ab NEW Value € *', $string)
```

where `$string` contains html data.

Comment: This would also replace the first price (64,00), wouldnt it?

Comment: if you don't want to replace `ab 64,00 € *` then use `'/ab 27,00 € */'` instead of `'/ab [0-9,] € */'`